# How to shorten the sentence with paralell words?

Tags: sentence-structure

Today I want to write a sentence with the full version is:

"**We use the same set of control variables as in our main regression that is controlling for firm-fixed effects and industry*year fixed effects and controlling for firm-level covariates and country-level covariates**"

What I shorten is as below:

"**We use  the same set of control variables as in our main regression that is controlling for firm and country-level covariates and controlling for firm and year*industry fixed effects**"

I am not sure whether it is correct and is there any better way to shorten or make it simpler?

Comment: I stared at these sentences for a while and I think I finally made sense of what you're trying to do. The structure of the change looks ok to me, but I don't know the jargon well enough to answer the question with certainty.  Is "effect" supposed to be plural or singular? You use it inconsistently?  Can the sentence be broken into multiple simpler sentences?

Comment: Hi @Readin . Thank you for your helps, the effect should be in plural form, I prefer to set it be in one sentence. Thanks a heap

Comment: question edited with thanks

Comment: This might be easier to read: "We use the same set of variables to control for firm and country-level covariates and for firm and year*industry fixed effects as we used in our main regression."  But don't trust me too much.  As I said, I don't fully understand the jargon you are using.

Comment: I think it is a nice paraphrase, thank Readin